# Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entitymanager

I want to migrate a project from spring boot 2.2.7 to spring boot 3.0.0.
For this I generated a fresh project with spring starter and beside what was generated I added few of my dependency's:

- lombok
- mapstruct
- sendgrid
- apache poi
- cloudinary
- hibernate-jpamodelgen

Full pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>chronos</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chronos</name>
    <description>Chronos booking system</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
        <version.hibernate-jpamodelgen>6.1.5.Final</version.hibernate-jpamodelgen>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- JSON Web Token Support -->
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>0.28.0-RC.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudinary-http44</artifactId>
            <version>1.33.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${version.hibernate-jpamodelgen}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>${java.version}</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId> <!-- IMPORTANT - LOMBOK BEFORE MAPSTRUCT -->
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArguments>-AaddGeneratedAnnotation=false</compilerArguments> <!-- suppress java.annotation -->
                            <processors>
                                <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                            </processors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.hibernate-jpamodelgen}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And I get this strange error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in file [WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myUserDetails': Error creating bean with name 'myUserDetails' defined in file [MyUserDetails.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.app.chronos.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: **Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'**

So WebSecurityConfig -> jwtTokenProvider -> myUserDetails -> userRepository -> entityManager -> **jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory** (who is this guy? )

Here is my config for Database

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.app.chronos.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

}
```

Tried to rename the entityManagerFactory using **entityManagerFactoryRef** but it does not help.

Has anyone some idea from where is this jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory is camming and what could be wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I replaced `is true` and `is false` by `= true` and `= false` in all my queries and it works

Comment: Forgot to updated the thread. Yes, this si also what I found and this fixt my issue :)

Comment: What exactly was the fix for this issue? Not sure what I'm missing here...

Comment: nativeQuery = true to false or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

For me, bumping [bumping the Hibernate version as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72763415/7769052) did the trick. Then all I had to do was to replace all imports from `javax.persistence` to `jakarta.persistence`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the dependencies of Spring Boot have the same version. This is most likely a compatibility issue, and somewhere in your pom (or gradle, etc.), you have a dependency which is not compatible with spring boot and the version must be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.properties file database connection and check your pom.xml if you have same dependacy for your database. For me in my pom was "h2", while I had the config for Postgress

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue code, but I don't know if it was the exactly problem. In my case, I just needed to manually name these two beans "entityManagerFactory" and "transactionManager".